# auto search with checkbox inside textbox from databases

Tags: javascript

I can able to load value from databases to text-box...so now  named as auto..from this i want to create a  auto search with multiple check box to select multiple value in text-box java script...its possible ...??

```
<form name="form1">
   <input type="checkbox" name="checkboxname" value="a">
   <input type="checkbox" name="checkboxname" value="b">
   <input type="checkbox" name="checkboxname" value="c">
</form>

<form name="form2">
    <input type="text" name="textname">
</form>

var textbox = document.getElementsByName("textname")[0];
var checkboxes = document.getElementsByName("checkboxname");
for (var i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++) {
    var checkbox = checkboxes[i];
    checkbox.onclick = (function(chk){
        return function() {
            var value = "";
            for (var j = 0; j < checkboxes.length; j++) {
                if (checkboxes[j].checked) {
                    if (value === "") {
                        value += checkboxes[j].value;
                    } else {
                        value += "," + checkboxes[j].value;
                    }
                }
            }
            textbox.value = value;
        }
    })(checkbox);
}
```

Comment: Not getting what u want to do.. Be specific...

Comment: i update the thread..so here if we click checkbox it take value..to textbox..but my need is if we type a word some thing like a,b,c in textbox it have to auto complete with  checkbox to select  multiple value...

Comment: any tips for this thread

Comment: what u r gettin here as an output???

Comment: this is an related example but my need is different (i.e)  if we type a word some word like a,b,c in textbox it have to auto complete with checkbox to select multiple value

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
<form name="form1" class="form_chk">
   <input type="checkbox" name="checkboxname" value="a" class="chk_box">a
   <input type="checkbox" name="checkboxname" value="b" class="chk_box">b
   <input type="checkbox" name="checkboxname" value="c" class="chk_box">c
</form>
```

```
$( "#txt_search" ).blur(function(e) {
  var $search = $(e.currentTarget),
  search_str = $search.val().toLowerCase(), $chk,

  $chk_ele = $('.chk_box').filter(function(index, chk){
if($(chk).val().toLowerCase().search(search_str) !== -1){
    return $(chk);  
}
  }); 
  $('.chk_box').prop('checked', false);
  $chk_ele.prop('checked', true);   
});
```

See the output : http://jsfiddle.net/J7dUz/

Comment: i think u have misunderstood my thread i can able to load a value in text-box so now i have to customize it like   if type a word some word like a,b,c in textbox it have to auto complete with checkbox to select multiple value

Comment: ok, yes misunderstood the question. sorry. then use jquery-ui autocomplete

Comment: is it possible do as my requirement

Comment: yah u can do it through it..... And please writedown your question in proper manner so that rest will understand it easily

Comment: go with jquery-ui autocomplete.